# How can I determine if a file has been set for an upload form, but not yet submitted?

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

Suppose I am using an HTML form to allow users to upload files to my website. How can I determine if they have already selected a file from their hard drive, but have NOT submitted the form. I want to use this information to determine if I should present some kind of alert to remind them to submit the form. I'm using PHP, so can I use `isset()`?

Comment: try `onchange` fo file input (js's onchange)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with PHP because it resides on the server side and cannot do anything with the browser until it submits the request.